# Why do i have to reenter the 'new organization' name when I have already entered it in the 'current employer' field

Tags: contacts

At some point the way 'new organisation' was created from the 'current employer' field on New Individual was changed/improved/updated.

If no match is found now (4.6/4.7) you can use a 'new organisation' link to create one. But having typed the name in to the 'current employer' field, the pop up then appears with the Organization Name field empty and it has to be retyped.

Seems like a functional regression since in the past you would type in the name only once.

Answer (score 1):

I recall tons of duplicate organisations created on < 4.6, because people wouldn't wait until the list of organisations was properly loaded and so on.

So in general, having a bit more control before creating a new organisation, and give it the chance to be more than an empty one makes sense IMO.

As your specific point, it would be better indeed that the field is pre-populated. PR welcome and all that ;)